# Spark lifecycle changes between Flex 4.5 and 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, components, lifecycle, flex-spark

I have recently migrated some of my projects to the shiny new Flex 4.6 SDK. I wasn't expecting much trouble since it was only a minor release. But as a matter of fact I got hundreds of errors all over the place. These errors would mostly come from Spark `SkinnableComponent`s; for example:

```
override protected function getCurrentSkinState():String {
    return mySkinPart.someProperty ? "normal" : "someOtherState";
}
```

would work just fine under 4.5, but would throw me a `nullpointer` error in 4.6. The reason is simple enough: in 4.6 `getCurrentSkinState()` is called before the skinparts are created, whereas in 4.5 I could be certain that the skinparts in the default state would be there.

Further investigation led me to believe that the initial state of a Skin is now `undefined` instead of the first state in the `States` array (until it calls `getCurrentSkinState()` that is).

Fixing these problems is usually pretty easy and requires just somewhat more defensive programming from my part. But that's not my real issue.

**The real issue** is that if the component lifecycle has changed, I'd like to know exactly *what* has changed and what parts of my projects might be affected.

I would be very appreciative if someone could shed some light on this or at least point me to the right place where I can read all about it (because the only release notes I could find were only covering the new mobile components).

---

**Edit** (this doesn't change the question; I just wanted to share my findings with you)

Another issue I just ran into: the `dynamic` modifier seems to no longer be inherited by subclasses. This is a pure ActionScript issue, so I guess it's the compiler that treats it differently.

Let me explain. Consider this class:

```
public class MyClass extends Array { }
```

Now, if I try to push a new item into this custom Array like this:

```
var t:Array = new MyClass();
t.push("hello");
```

- SDK 4.5.1: no problem
- SDK 4.6: "Cannot create property 0 on MyClass" at runtime

Apparently that's because Array is dynamic and MyClass isn't, so it's easily fixed:

```
public dynamic class MyClass extends Array { }
```

and the error's gone.

But what if I used a third-party library that has code like this and to which I had no source code access? My application would break and there's no way I could fix it. I mean: come on, that's no minor change for a dot-release.

Comment: I've ecountered this too, i assume its a bug. As i see occurs, if you try to access skin parts before the component is initalizes. My "solution" is to access the skinparts in the next frame using callLater()

Comment: @sydd I don't think it's a bug. It's a consistent change in the framework and I want to know more about it. If you want to know when a skinpart is available, just override `partAdded()`. Using callLater() isn't exactly pretty.

Comment: @RIAstar Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having some significant issues updating to 4.6 from 4.5 (as [detailed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840098/upgrading-to-flex-4-6-from-flex-4-5)) and it would absolutely make my day if you had some insight.

Comment: @NoobsArePeople2 I was able to fix all the issues as described in my question (just avoiding nullpointers with skinparts in `getCurrentSkinState()`), but I'm not certain it's the same issue you're having.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two questions in there.

> 1 ) The real issue is that if the component lifecycle has changed, I'd
>   like to know exactly what has changed and what parts of my projects
>   might be affected.

I haven't seen a comprehensive low-level analysis of the differences between the two version. If you are really concerned, and you have the time to spare, you could use a diff tool to compare the source code for the two SDK's. There shouldn't be too many major structural changes - e.g. renamed classes or packages, so it might not be so bad. I expect a lot of classes won't have changed at all.

> 2 ) Another issue I just ran into: the dynamic modifier seems to no longer
>   be inherited by subclasses. This is a pure ActionScript issue, so I
>   guess it's the compiler that treats it differently.

This one is easier. `dynamic` has never been inherited. `Object` is dynamic, so if the attribute was inherited every class would have to be dynamic too.

If there appears to be a change in behaviour related to dynamic class instances, then there is something else going on in your code.

Comment: 1) As I see it: it breaks my code, so it's a major change. Things are clearly being executed in a different order on component initialization. The diff tool is a good tip, but a changelog that I can just read would be a whole lot nicer. I just found [one for Flex 4.5](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+4.5+Backwards+Compatibility), but nothing for 4.6

Comment: 2) There is 'nothing else going on in my code': my code is exactly as I've written it in my question (just a class extending Array with no added functionality). The only thing that has changed between the two versions is the compiler.

Comment: I've done some more testing on nr.2 and it would seem like this was actually a bug that is now fixed. It _should_ - as you describe - never have been possible to do what I did. Nevertheless, it was.

Comment: Interesting. Which exact version of the sdk did you test with? I was only able to see the expected behaviour.

Comment: 4.5.1 The funny thing is: I can `push`, I can `pop`, I can iterate with a `for each` loop and after a `push` the FB debugger shows the property `0` with its value. But I do get an error when I try to access it through `myArray[0]` or even when I simply trace the array (tracing implicitely calls `toString` which calls `join` which is the method that fails). With 4.6 it fails immediately when I `push`, as it should.