# What's the trick to inheriting from a Dictionary in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, inheritance, dictionary

Given the following code:

```
import flash.utils.Dictionary;

import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
import mx.controls.Alert;

public class CDictionary extends Dictionary
{
    public function CDictionary(weakKeys:Boolean=false)
    {
        super(weakKeys);
    }
}
```

this raises Error #1056:

```
m_cdictNearIDs = new CDictionary();
m_cdictNearIDs[4] = "f";
```

but this doesn't:

```
m_cdictNearIDs = new Dictionary();
m_cdictNearIDs[4] = "f";
```

(In each case, it's a member variable that's declared to be of the same type it's instantiated as.)  Wth?  What's the trick to inheriting from dictionary?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must define your class as `dynamic`:

```
package
{
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;

    public dynamic class CDictionary extends Dictionary
    {
        public function CDictionary(weakKeys:Boolean=false)
        {
            super(weakKeys);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, apparently it actually depends on the compiler you're using; see the second part of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502204/spark-lifecycle-changes-between-flex-4-5-and-4-6

Comment: I'm very surprised at the whole thing.  Well, that's a lot simpler than what I was expecting.  Thanks man.

Comment: Classes are `sealed` by default.